# Can I say "Is this yours book"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I know that it's acceptable to say "Is this book - yours", but I'm asking about the other form of: "Is this yours book"? 
Is it correct construction?

Comment: "your is used + a noun, "yours" without a noun.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is *"Is this yours book?"* correct?
No, it's **not** correct.

---

You seem to be confused by ***this*** and ***your/yours***.

***This*** can work as a "determiner". It can also work as a "demonstrative pronoun".

> ***This book*** is mine. -- *This* is a determiner. A determiner **is used with** a noun.
>   ***This*** is a book. -- *This* is a "demonstrative pronoun". It's a pronoun. It **works like** a noun.

***Your*** is a "possessive determiner".
***Yours*** is a "possessive pronoun".

> *That book is **your book***. -- *Your* is a possessive determiner. It's **used with** a noun.
>   *That book is **yours***. -- *Your**s*** is a possessive pronoun. It **works like** a noun.

In the last sentence (*"That book is **yours**"*), ***yours*** = ***your book***.

---

If English is still new to you, I'd recommend turning a question ("interrogative sentence") into a plain, non-question sentence ("declarative sentence") first. It's easier to understand declarative sentences. Let's start with *"Is this book yours?"*, which you know that it's acceptable:

> *Is this book yours?*
>   (~ ***This book*** is **yours**.) -- *This* is a **determiner**. *Yours* is a possessive **pronoun**.

Let's try other variants:

> *Is this book your book?*
>   (~ ***This book*** is **your book**.) -- *This* is a **determiner**. *Your* is a possessive **determiner**.
>
> *Is this your book?*
>   (~ ***This*** is **your book**.) -- *This* is a demonstrative **pronoun**. *Your* is a possessive **determiner**.
>
> *Is this yours?*
>   (~ ***This*** is **yours**.) -- *This* is a demonstrative **pronoun**. *Yours* is a possessive **pronoun**.

Why can't you use *"Is this yours book?"*?

Because ***yours*** is already a (possessive) pronoun. It works like a noun. If you use *yours* to mean "your book", your sentence could be understood like this:

> *Is this yours book?* <-- **DO NOT USE THIS!**
>   (~ ***This*** is **yours** book)
>   (~ ***This*** is **your book** book) -- *"This is your book book"* doesn't make any sense!

And that's why *"Is this yours book?"* is **not** correct.

---

**Bonus:** [Table of basic personal pronouns of English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_personal_pronouns#Table_of_basic_personal_pronouns) on Wikipedia could be useful. It covers all English personal pronouns. I recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

No. As a native speaker I would say:

> Is this your book?

I would also say, while holding or pointing at the book:

> Is this yours?

(I'll leave it to the grammarians to explain nature of these forms)

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language as well.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Actually, I don't know why it is correct! I just know it is.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 btw I think 莱恩 is for Ryan while Brian should be
 拜恩

Comment: @tom10271 Thanks. I ended up choosing 莱恩 because I preferred the characters, after a long talk with native calligraphers; but your insight is useful.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can say "Is this your book?" Don't add the s after "your" unless if you ask "Is this book yours?"