# Demonstrative Pronoun + noun

Tags: determiners, fused-determiner

Probably this question is too imbecile but I need to ask:

If a pronoun replaces a noun why in English language **this, that, these, those** are called 'pronouns' when they are used + a noun?

I understand when **this, that, these, those** are used as pronouns:

> Who's **that**?
>   
>   Whose shoes do you prefer - **these** or **those**?

But I don't understand why **this** is still called a 'demonstrative pronoun' in this situation:

> Do you like **this** picture?

Shouldn't be called something else?

Comment: It's indeed something else! -- A recent answer of mine could be helpful: [Can I say "Is this yours book"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/68527/3281)

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, I was fooled by a grammar website that  does not mention determiners - http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/This_That_These_Those.htm. So, I infer that they are called **demonstrative determiners**, isn't it? Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Traditional grammar calls *this* a “demonstrative adjective” when it is used this way. Many words of this sort—for instance, *this*, *that*, *some*, *all*, *most*, *which* and numbers like *one*, *three*, *ten*—have this sort of dual use.

A more modern grammatical treatment classifies these words as “determinatives”, in the same category as the articles *a/an* and *the*. *This*, specifically, is classified as a *demonstrative determiner*.  Their “core” syntactical use of determinatives is as “determiners” introducing a noun phrase to help determine what entity you are referring to. Most (but not all) determinatives can also “stand for” an entire noun phrase, if that has already been defined in the discourse. In this case this treatment speaks of a “fused-head determiner” rather than a “pronoun”: the noun “fused into” the determiner.

As DamkerngT points out, several personal pronouns have distinct forms for uses of the possessive as a fused-head determiner: *my* becomes *mine*, *your→yours*, *her→hers*, *our→ours*, *their→theirs*.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the answer I was looking for!